# filtering a column with awk + if statement not working

Tags: awk

how do i filter a column using awk?

This is alll the column:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print $7} NR>1{print $7;}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv
"Product_Description"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"$39.95 Plan"
"$69.95 Plan"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"$19 CO COMBO - NOT RECURRENT"
"$39.95 Plan"
"PREPAY PLUS - $1 - #33"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
```

Now I just want to show lines with this `"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"` but my if oes not seem to be working. **How do I make it work?**

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print $7} NR>1{if($7=="PREPAY PLUS - $0 -") print $7;}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv
"Product_Description"
```

Comment: I think double quotes are missing.

Comment: tried that but no joy `$ awk -F'|' 'NR==1{print $7} NR>1{if($7==""PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"") print $7;}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv
"Product_Description"` I know it is something along them lines.

Comment: can you post sample file input and sample output you expect.. may be a simple `grep` command might suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' -v dq='"' 'NR==1{print $7} NR>1{if($1==dq"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"dq) print $7;}' test.in
"Product_Description"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
```

Comment: tks that was it `awk -F'|' -v dq='"' 'NR==1{print $7} NR>1{if($7==dq"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"dq) print $7;}' head_datafile_pipe_deleimiter.csv
"Product_Description"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"
`